# Facebook login pop-up not showing, but still return a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook-graph-api

i'm using [Angular facebook service](https://github.com/AlmogBaku/ngFacebook)
in the controller, i'm trying to use the method: $facebook.login() when clicking on a button, using ng-click.

the promise is returned and the code inside is activated, but there is no login pop-up.
also tried to turn-off the chrome pop-up blocker.
there are no errors on the console ...

here are my code samples:

**facebook.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>please log in</h3>
        <button type="Log In" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="login()">Log In</button>
    </div>
```

**facebook.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ngsocial.facebook', ['ngRoute', 'ngFacebook'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/facebook', {
      templateUrl: 'facebook/facebook.html',
      controller: 'facebookCtrl'
    });
  }])
  .config(function($facebookProvider) {
    $facebookProvider.setAppId('1816664965234931');
    $facebookProvider.setPermissions("email", "public_profile", "user_posts", "publish_actions", "user_photos");
  })
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
      }
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


    (function() {
      console.log("im loaded");
    }());
  })


.controller('facebookCtrl', ["$scope" , "$facebook" , function($scope,$facebook) {
  $scope.login = function () {
    $facebook.login().then (console.log("promise has returned"));
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$facebook.login().then (console.log("promise has returned"));
```

does not mean the promise has been returned ... what you've done there is passed the return value of an immediately executed console.log as the callback function to `.then` - in Promises, passing in a non function as a callback is "do nothing" - for example

```
somePromise.then(undefined).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

will log the fulfilled value of `somePromise` = it's like `.then(undefined)` wasn't even there - there's a reason for this - because in browsers where `.catch` can't be used (due to `catch` being a reserved word), you would do the catch like `.then(null, function(err) { ... });` - because `.then` actually takes two arguments, onfulfilled and onrejected

if you change your code to

```
.then(function(data) { 
    console.log(data); 
})
.catch(function(err) { 
     console.log('error', err); 
});
```

You will see the **actual** results of `$facebook.login()` - most likely there will be an error as you say the popup isn't happening

> If you want to ascertain exactly what `$facebook.login()` returns

```
var p = $facebook.login();
console.log('p is', p);
p.then(function(data) { 
    console.log('data is', data); 
})
.catch(function(err) { 
     console.log('error', err); 
});
```

If `p` above is a Promise, then you should see

```
p is Promise { <state>: "pending" }
```

in firefox - other browsers will possible show something different

if you see that p is a promise, and neither the .then nor the .catch is called, that means the promise returned by that function never fulfills

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. however ... still no error ... and this time, it's not printing what's inside the promise ....
.controller('facebookCtrl', ["$scope" , "$facebook" , function($scope,$facebook) {
  $scope.login = function () {
    $facebook.login().then(function(data) { 
    console.log(data); 
})
.catch(function(err) { 
     console.log('error', err); 
});
  }
}